# Perform arithmetic on a singly linked list which represent a large number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list which represents the large number `2253239487.`

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
        
def __repr__(self):
    return '{0}'.format(self.val)
```

The `ListNode` instance is populated as below:

```
h1 = ListNode(2)
n2 = ListNode(2)
n3 = ListNode(5)
n4 = ListNode(3)
n5 = ListNode(2)
n6 = ListNode(3)
n7 = ListNode(9)
n8 = ListNode(4)
n9 = ListNode(8)
n10 = ListNode(7)

h1.next = n2
n2.next = n3
n3.next = n4
n4.next = n5
n5.next = n6
n6.next = n7
n7.next = n8
n8.next = n9
n9.next = n10
```

Now, I want to `divide the number by 3` and `return` the answer as a `whole number.`

I have written below code but it is giving wrong result:

```
sum = 0
head = h1
while head.next:
     sum += head.val
     head = head.next
return sum // 3
```

There is an assumption that the "sum" integer is too big for the integer object. What is the best way to directly calculate avg without storing sum in memory?

Comment: Is the result really supposed to be an int, not a linked list? Is this a coding challenge online somewhere?

Comment: The result has to be an integer and not a linked list.

Comment: But under the answer you just said it's too big for that. So you're saying the desired result is impossible? Then your question makes no sense.

Comment: The "sum" integer is too big for the integer object. So, we need to directly calculate avg.

Comment: How can it be too big? It takes far less memory than the linked list. How big is it?

Comment: This sounds like a challenge designed for languages with fixed-size integers, then awkwardly ported to a bunch of other languages for more views or because the challenge site required it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't represent the linked list as an integer, then you need to do long division on the values in the list. You can do this by iterating divide by 3 over the nodes to generate new nodes, and then joining the nodes before finally outputting the result:

```py
divisor = 3
nodes = []
head = h1
r = 0
while head:
    v = r * 10 + head.val
    q = v // divisor
    r = v % divisor
    if q != 0 or head != h1:
        nodes.append(ListNode(q))
    head = head.next

for i, n in enumerate(nodes[:-1]):
    n.next = nodes[i+1]

head = nodes[0]
while head:
    print(head.val, end='')
    head = head.next

print()
```

Output:

```
751079829
```

Note that *if* the divisor could be larger than the input number (for testing purposes) then this would give a string of `0`s as the result. You can work around this by changing the `if` test to only add a leading `0` if we are at the last node in the list:

```py
divisor = 3
nodes = []
head = h1
r = 0
while head:
    v = r * 10 + head.val
    q = v // divisor
    r = v % divisor
    if q != 0 or len(nodes) > 0 or head.next is None:
        nodes.append(ListNode(q))
    head = head.next

for i, n in enumerate(nodes[:-1]):
    n.next = nodes[i+1]

head = nodes[0]
while head:
    print(head.val, end='')
    head = head.next

print()
```

Note also that if you generate your list in reverse order you can save all the assignments to `.next`:

```py
n10 = ListNode(7)
n9 = ListNode(8, n10)
n8 = ListNode(4, n9)
n7 = ListNode(9, n8)
n6 = ListNode(3, n7)
n5 = ListNode(2, n6)
n4 = ListNode(3, n5)
n3 = ListNode(5, n4)
n2 = ListNode(2, n3)
h1 = ListNode(2, n2)
```

Comment: Thanks. There is an assumption that there is not enough memory to store value of `sum`. What is the best way to retrieve the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... how could your code work if that is the situation? Also a linked list takes a lot more memory than an integer. Or do you mean that the integer is too big for the integer data type?

Comment: Integer is too big for the integer data type.

Comment: @meallhour see my edit...

Comment: can you please help me understand need for `if q != 0 or head != h1:`?

Comment: @meallhour that was just to avoid a leading `0` in the result. So basically as long as the quotient `q` is not zero, or we're not doing division on the first number in the list, we always add `q` to the new nodes list. But if the result of the first divide is `0` (as it would be in this case) it prevents the list having a leading `0` on it. If you modify the code to remove the `if` and always `nodes.append(ListNode(q))` you will see the leading zero.

Comment: @Nick: You forgot to handle the case where the quotient of the whole long division is just 0, though.

Comment: @user2357112 true... but that would imply that the divisor was bigger than the input number and the input number is supposed to be too large to represent as an integer, meaning the divisor would be too. However I've added code to deal with that to the answer.